Error bound on inverting a polynomial approximation to a function
I am trying to analyze the error of a numerical algorithm I'm using. I have an "expensive to compute" function $f(x) \in C^{\infty}$ that I need to invert many times, and I know that $x\in [x_0,x_1]$. So I pre-compute a piecewise polynomial interpolation of $f$ (and of $f'$) with a uniform step-size of $\Delta x$ and a polynomial interpolant of order $n$; these interpolations then have an error of $\left(\Delta x\right)^{n+1}$.
I then apply a Newton solver to this approximated $f$ (using the approximated $f'$ as well) and iterate until the error is machine zero (so I disregard the error due to the non-linear solver).
So my question is, how is the error of $x(f_0)$ (where $f_0$ is some value of $f$ I'm trying to invert) related to $\Delta x$? Is it also of order $\left(\Delta x\right)^{n+1}$? I could not find any related analysis in numerical textbooks/papers.

Why not simply use reverse polynomial interpolation on the same data segments? Is it important to hit the exact inverse of the forward interpolation, or just to get a reasonable approximation of the inverse of the original function?

Yes, using reverse interpolation is an option in this specific case, but in a more general setting, the function $f$ is dependent on several variables, all but one of which are fixed (so I am dealing with a one-variable function at the end of the day), but only at the last moment — so constructing a reverse interpolation is not possible as the values of the other variables are not know beforehand.

The solution turned out be pretty straightforward:
Let $p(x)$ be the approximation of $f$, $f_0$ be the given value, $x_0$ be the point at which $f(x_0) = f_0$, and $\tilde{x}_0$ be the point at which $p(\tilde{x}_0)=f_0$. So given a statement about the closeness of $f$ and $p$ I am looking for a statement on the closeness of $x_0$ and $\tilde{x}_0$.
Since $f$ is differentiable, we apply the mean value theorem (I assume that $\tilde{x}_0 > x_0$, the other case is done by analogy):
$$
    \frac{f(\tilde{x}_0) - f(x_0)}{\tilde{x}_0 - x_0} = f'(c),\: c \in [x_0,\tilde{x}_0]
$$
We have that $f(x_0) = f_0 = p(\tilde{x}_0)$, so we can write that
$$
    \left| \tilde{x}_0 - x_0 \right| =  \frac{\left|f(\tilde{x}_0) - f(x_0)\right|}{\left|f'(c)\right|}=\frac{\left|f(\tilde{x}_0) -  p(\tilde{x}_0)\right|}{\left|f'(c)\right|} \leq \frac{C_1 (\Delta x)^n} {\left|f'(c)\right|}.
$$
So if $f'$ is bounded from below by a non-zero constant, the difference between the solutions is also bounded by $(\Delta x)^n$.
